# Syntax error when running configure in binutils

Tags: syntax-error, cross-compiling, binutils

Was building a cross compiler from C to the i686 processor with the elf file structure. When I ran configure for binutils, it ran until creating config.status and gave the error:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
./config.status: line 470: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./config.status: line 470: `    *\'*) ac_optarg=`$as_echo "$ac_optarg" | sed "s/'/'\\\\\\\\''/g"` ;;'[
```

for reference, I am on MacOS 10.14.6, building binutils-2.37,
and I am following the [OSDev GCC Cross-Compiler Tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler).
These are the configure options I used:

`toolchain/i686-elf-source/binutils-2.37/configure --target=i686-elf --prefix="toolchain/i686-elf-build" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror` (Note that `pwd=toolchain/i686-elf-build/binutils-build`)

The expected result looks like this:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating makefile
```

The syntax error was oddly specific, and I could not find any similar syntax errors while searching. I had previously tried a different prefix, but it still didn't work. I am still a beginner in bash, so I couldn't find what the core of the error was in config.status, and I am still trying to find similar issues.

I would definitely appreciate help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found that it was a misbehaving quote. Here are some snippets:

```
srcdir='../../i686-elf-source/binutils-2.37'
INSTALL='/usr/bin/install -c'
'AWK='awk' # The starting single quote is my horrible patch
test -n "$AWK" || AWK=awk
```

^ Code where the error really started

and

```
  -recheck | --recheck | --rechec | --reche | --rech | --rec | --re | --r)
    ac_cs_recheck=: ;;
  --version | --versio | --versi | --vers | --ver | --ve | --v | -V )
    $as_echo "$ac_cs_version"; exit ;;
  --config | --confi | --conf | --con | --co | --c )
    $as_echo "$ac_cs_config"; exit ;;
  --debug | --debu | --deb | --de | --d | -d )
    debug=: ;;
  --file | --fil | --fi | --f )
    $ac_shift
    case $ac_optarg in
    *\'*) ac_optarg=`$as_echo "$ac_optarg" | sed "s/'/'\\\\\\\\''/g"` ;; # The error line
    '') as_fn_error $? "missing file argument" ;;
    esac
```

^ Where the error was shown

Welp, that was 2 weeks I'm never getting back. If someone gets a similar error, I hope this helps!